Find stationary distribution, given a replacement kernel
I would like to show that, given a random kernel $R=(R_x)_{x\in\mathbb{N}}$, defined by $$R_x=-\delta_x+\delta_0+\delta_{x+1},$$ the Markov chain of kernel $(R_x)_{x\in\mathbb{N}}$ has unique stationary distribution $\pi_x=2^{−x−1}$ $ (\forall x\ge0)$.
My interpretation of this kernel, is that,

With rate $1$, from a state $x$ the chain jumps to state $0$ ($\delta_0$).
With rate 1, from state $x$ the chain jumps to $x+1$ ($\delta_{x+1})$.
I say that the rate of leaving state $x$ ($\delta_x$) is $-2$ to compensate the other rates, since the sum of rates should be $0$.

So the rate matrix has the form $$Q=\begin{bmatrix}-1&1&0&0&0&\dots\\1&-2&1&0&0&\dots\\1&0&-2&1&0&\dots\\\vdots&&&&\ddots\end{bmatrix}.$$
Using the balanced equations, we get, $$2\pi_x=\pi_0+\pi_{x+1},$$ in particular $\pi_1=\pi_0$, $\pi_2=2\pi_1-\pi_0=\pi_0$, and iteratively, for every $x\in\mathbb{N}$, $$\pi_x=\pi_0.$$
Then, it must hold $\sum_x\pi_x=1$, but $$\sum_{x\ge0}\pi_x=\sum_{x\ge0}\pi_0=\infty,$$ since $\pi_0$ is a constant and does not depend on $x$. This suggests that the chain does not have a stationary distribution.
Did I misinterpret something, or what should I do differently?
For a reference see section 2.2.1 of this paper.

If you can find a probability measure satisfying the DBC, then it is stationary. This is not always the case, and you provided an example...
The definition of a stationary distribution is a probability measure $\pi$ $\pi Q = 0$, or, explicitly:
$$ (*)\quad \sum_{i } \pi(i) Q_{i,j}=0$$
for all $j$. Note that the summation is over the column $j$. In our case we have the following system:
\begin{cases}  -\pi(0)+\sum_{i=1}^\infty \pi (i) =0.\\  
  \pi(j-1) -2 \pi(j) =0 & ~j=1,2,\dots.\end{cases}
Solving the second system gives $\pi(j) = 2^{-j} \pi(0)$ for $j=1,2,\dots$, and the first equation automatically holds. It remains to normalize this into a probability measure. This is done by setting $\pi(0)=\frac 12$.
Therefore the unique stationary distribution is $\pi(j) = 2^{-j+1}$, a (shifted) geometric.
Note. If you can find a probability measure satisfying the DBC $\pi(i) Q_{i,j} = \pi(j) Q_{j,i}$ for all $i\ne j$, then it is stationary. To see this simply sum over all $j$ on both sides and conclude that $(*)$ holds. However, in the specific case this is not possible.
